# How to define a nested list in django for json response

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am new to Django and so I thought of creating basic app that represents operations in a shipping company. I have a WorkOrder which contains Shipments. So my models.py contains the following :

```
class WorkOrder (models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=300,default = "New")
    source = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=
    material = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    shipmentlist = [] //PROBLEMATIC CODE

class Shipment (models.Model):
    expected_startDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    expected_endDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    shipment_status = models.CharField(max_length=300,default = "Not Started")
```

I have 2 serializers WorkOrderSerializer and ShipmentSerializer which i have defined in serialzers.py. I want to return a list of shipment contained within a Work Order object.

```
class WorkOrderSerializer        
    generated_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="New")
    source = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    shipmentlist = ShipmentSerializer(many=True)

class ShipmentSerializer
    expected_startDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    expected_endDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    shipment_status = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="Not Started")
```

I am following the model specified here. 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects

In my views.py I am calling the serializer when I get the request like this

```
def workorder_operations(request,workorder_pk):
    workorder = Work_Order.objects.filter(pk=workorder_pk)
    serializer = Work_Order_Serializer(workorder)
```

What this produces is a json that looks like the following

```
{
    "shipmentlist":[]
}
```

I am completely confused about two things :

1. why it shows ONLY shipment object and not the others even if it cannot parse the data or something.
2. why doesn't shipment get populated.

When I used the ModelSerializer instead and defined the serializer this way it all worked perfectly fine:

```
class ShipmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Shipment
        fields =('expected_startDate','expected_endDate','shipment_status')
class WorkOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrder
        fields =('request_id','generated_date','status', 'source','destination','material')
```

What I want to know is how do I represent a nested list of objects so that they can be serialized properly. 
I want my json for a WorkOrder object to look something like this: (Note: the variable names in the json and models might have a mismatch so please overlook that as I have stripped some of the variables to not complicate the example here.)

```
{
"id": "WO20170912",
"source": "BBSR",
"destination": "RKL",
"customer_id": 1,
"material": "Granite",
"weight": 19,
"status": "ALLOCATED",
"shipments": [
  {
    "id":"SH01234",
    "work_order_id": "WO20170912",
    "source": "BBSR",
    "destination": "RKL"
  },
  {
    "id":"SH01255",
    "work_order_id": "WO20170912",
    "source": "BBSR",
    "destination": "RKL"
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `ManyToManyField` in `WorkOrder` model,

```
class Shipment (models.Model):
    expected_startDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    expected_endDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    shipment_status = models.CharField(max_length=300,default = "Not Started")


class WorkOrder (models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=300,default = "New")
    source = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=
    material = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    shipments = models.ManyToManyField(Shipment, related_name='shipments')
```

Serializers would be like,

```
class ShipmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Shipment
        fields = [f.name for f in model._meta.fields]

class WorkOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shipments = ShipmentSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrder
        fields = [f.name for f in model._meta.fields] + ['shipments']
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I get the following error when i try to hit the URL: no such table: workorder_shipments. My database doesn't have any shipments currently so i was expecting it to show me an empty list of shipments with the rest of the data for the work order. Also as an additional point, I made partial entry into the database for workorder where in I did not put any shipment data. Did I have to? Just making sure I didn't go wrong somewhere you assumed I wouldn't :)

Comment: Did you migrate the database?

Comment: Damn! That was the missing link! Thank you so much for your help! :-)